# Expansion in \numexpr...\relax versus \pdfstrcmp

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, expansion, e-tex, pdfstrcmp

The `\numexpr...\relax` construction in eTeX allows to evaluate numerical expressions, and it expands tokens fully as it goes.

The `\pdfstrcmp{...}{...}` construction in pdfTeX lets us compare two lists of tokens after full expansion and conversion to a string (with `\detokenize`).

Are there specific token lists (parameter-less macros) `\foo` such that `\the\numexpr\foo\relax` correctly produces an integer, but `\pdfstrcmp{\foo}{}` causes a TeX error? It seems that the expansion behaviour is the same in both cases, but one converts its argument to an integer, and the other one to a string.

Comment: `\numexpr` doesn't fully expand tokens in the same sense of `\edef`; it stops expanding as soon as it finds something that can't be interpreted as a numexpr; if this token happens to be `\relax`, it is swallowed. I'd say it's a particular case of what `\pdfstrcmp` does.

Comment: @egreg: true. Note that I put the requirement that `\the\numexpr\foo\relax` correctly produces an integer. So `\def\foo{1+2X\junk}` is not eligible for instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two cases where `\the\numexpr...\relax` works, but `\pdfstrcmp{}{...}` will blow up, excluding the obvious case where `...` is replaced by `0\relax\undefined`, terminating the `\numexpr` prematurely.

1. TeX interprets `` `\a `` as a number, without expanding `\a`. Hence, `` \the\numexpr`\a\relax `` expands to `97` (the character code of `a`), whereas `` \pdfstrcmp{}{`\a} `` blows up if `\a` is not defined.
2. Using `\protected` control sequences can also cause trouble, because those are forcefully expanded "from the left" in a `\numexpr`, but will not be expanded by `\pdfstrcmp`. Take for instance

   ```
   \protected\def\gob#1{}
   \the\numexpr 0\gob\undefined  \relax
   \pdfstrcmp{}{0\gob\undefined}
   ```

In the case of `\numexpr`, `\gob` is expanded and removes the `\undefined` control sequence. In the second case, however, the `\edef`-like expansion leaves the `\protected` control sequence `\gob` untouched, and goes on to expand `\undefined`, which is, well, undefined.

The original goal I had was to define a macro which takes in an argument which can be either empty or an integer expression, and evaluates the integer expression or puts a default value in the case of an empty argument. It seemed illogical to perform expansion in the `\numexpr` case but not for the emptyness test, and I was thinking of testing with `\pdfstrcmp{}{...}`. That can't work. An uglier but more correct choice is the following:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\evaluate#1{\expandafter\evaluate@\the\numexpr#1\z@\z@\relax}
\def\evaluate@#1\z@#2\relax{#1}

\evaluate{1+2+3}
\evaluate{\empty}
\evaluate{\@gobble\a}
\evaluate{`\a}
```

If the argument to `\evaluate` is empty or expands to an empty argument, the `\numexpr` expansion will go through all of it and reach the first `\z@`, evaluating that to `0` (default value), then stop because `\z@` does not make sense in an integer expression there. The auxiliary cleans up.

On the other hand, if the argument to `\evaluate` is a correct integer expression, it is evaluated, and `\numexpr` stops expanding when encountering the first `\z@`, and the cleaning up macro removes both `\z@`.

I just thought of a better way: "`f`-expand" (expand fully from the left, stopping at the first non-expandable token, removing it in case it is a space) the argument before testing for emptyness:

```
\def\evaluate#1{\expandafter\evaluate@\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}}
\def\evaluate@#1{\the\numexpr\ifcat X\detokenize{#1}X\z@\fi#1\relax}
```

If the argument is empty or will expand to become empty, `` \romannumeral-`0#1 `` expands to nothing, and the test in `\evaluate@` is true, which means we insert `\z@` (default value). Otherwise `#1` is evaluated.

Comment: Good catch about `\a`.

Comment: @egreg Also, I realized now that when the default is `0`, I can simply do `\the\numexpr#1+\z@\relax`. But I don't think that can be adapted to any other default.

Comment: If `#1` is a correct integer expression, isn't also `#1+3` again a correct integer expression?

Comment: @egreg yes, but I need `{}`=> default and `{123}`=>`123`, not `123+default`.

Comment: Bruno: What of `\the\numexpr 0\gobb\undefined\relax`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa I don't understand what `\gobb` is. If it is `\protected\def\gobb#1{}` as in my answer, then I already discussed it: works in a `\numexpr`, doesn't work in `\pdfstrcmp`.